# zip is not working in the same way on 4.2 to 6.0

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a customisation in version 4.2 and works, now i'm working on version 6 but the custom is not working in the same way. 
i want to compress one folder with files in there. 
Could you help me with this problem ? what is the new way doing the same? :(

here is my code:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (PX.Data.Update.ZipArchive zip = new PX.Data.Update.ZipArchive(stream, false))
            {
                zip.AddFolder(direc);
            }
            string path = "ArchivosXML.zip";
            PX.SM.FileInfo info = new PX.SM.FileInfo(path, null, stream.ToArray());
            throw new PXRedirectToFileException(info, true);
        }
```

Comment: What you mean _is not working in the same way_?  How does version 6 work differently?

Comment: @Quantic His question is tagged C# and acumatica, and from a short Google those classes seem to be acumatica classes, i'm assuming it's also the version of the acumatica too he's talking about

Comment: yes those are valid Acumatica product versions. I would agree that the needs to be some explanation as to what is different and not working? errors? behavior? etc...

Comment: sorry ,  the problem is , PX.Data.Update.ZipArchive is not there anymore, could you help me telling me how to call that function on version 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the **ZipArchive** class was moved from `PX.Data.Update` namespace to  `PX.Common`.

Below are 2 samples, that perfectly work on 6.0, showing how to:

- synchronously export all attachments from current Sales Order into a Zip archive:

  ```
  public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
      public PXAction<SOOrder> ExportAttachmnts;
      [PXButton]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Export Attachments")]
      protected void exportAttachmnts()
      {
          var order = Base.Document.Current;

          using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
          {
              using (PX.Common.ZipArchive archive = PX.Common.ZipArchive.CreateFrom(stream, false))
              {
                  UploadFileMaintenance upload = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();

                  Guid[] uids = PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(Base.Document.Cache, order);
                  foreach (Guid uid in uids)
                  {
                      PX.SM.FileInfo fileInfo = upload.GetFile(uid);
                      archive.AddFile(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.BinData);
                  }
              }
              PX.SM.FileInfo info = new PX.SM.FileInfo(
                  string.Format("{0}-{1}-Attachmets.zip", order.OrderType, order.OrderNbr),
                  null, stream.ToArray());
              throw new PXRedirectToFileException(info, true);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- asynchronously export all attachments from current Sales Order in a Zip archive:

  ```
  public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
      public PXAction<SOOrder> ExportAttachmnts;
      [PXButton]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Export Attachments")]
      protected void exportAttachmnts()
      {
          var order = Base.Document.Current;

          PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, () =>
          {
              using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
              {
                  using (PX.Common.ZipArchive archive = PX.Common.ZipArchive.CreateFrom(stream, false))
                  {
                      UploadFileMaintenance upload = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();

                      Guid[] uids = PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(Base.Document.Cache, order);
                      foreach (Guid uid in uids)
                      {
                          PX.SM.FileInfo fileInfo = upload.GetFile(uid);
                          archive.AddFile(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.BinData);
                      }
                  }
                  PX.SM.FileInfo info = new PX.SM.FileInfo(
                      string.Format("{0}-{1}-Attachmets.zip", order.OrderType, order.OrderNbr),
                      null, stream.ToArray());
                  throw new PXRedirectToFileException(info, true);
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```